# Problem while configuring CodeWorld through cabal run

Tags: haskell, cabal, codeworld

For our labs in uni, we had a few instructions to follow to use CodeWorld and one of them was to run `cabal v2-run` in the terminal for the file. When I had installed Haskell, it showed warning messages saying that cabal run was partially broken (I don't have the exact error message as of now),but it installed just fine. ghci works too.

However, while running this command, it builds up until a certain patch and then shows this error:

```
Building     blank-canvas-0.7.4 (lib)
Installing   patch-0.0.8.2 (lib)
Completed    patch-0.0.8.2 (lib)

Failed to build blank-canvas-0.7.4.
Build log (
C:\cabal\logs\ghc-9.2.5\blank-canvas-0.7.4-5a6633f27b307e0e478b425211ca323972f09372.log      
):
[ 1 of 17] Compiling Graphics.Blank.Events ( Graphics\Blank\Events.hs, dist\build\Graphics\Blank\Events.o )
ghc-9.2.5.exe: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
  (GHC version 9.2.5:
        loadArchive "C:\\ghcup\\ghc\\9.2.5\\mingw\\lib\\libz.dll.a": failed

Please report this as a GHC bug:  https://www.haskell.org/ghc/reportabug

ghc-9.2.5.exe: Could not load `zlib1.dll'. Reason: addDLL: zlib1.dll or dependencies not loaded. (Win32 error 126)

Error: cabal-3.10.2.1.exe: Failed to build blank-canvas-0.7.4 (which is
required by exe:Main from comp1100-lab04-0.1.1). See the build log above for
details.
```

Is there any way I could resolve this? I have checked that I'm running the command in right directory. This error came up several minutes into the installation. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Haskell recently because this command was showing another error message(`Build process terminated with exit code 11`), but I don't know if that would be relevant here since I already uninstalled and reinstalled haskell, cabal,and ghcup

Comment: Does this GHC otherwise work?

Comment: GHC 9.2.5 is a bit outdated, there have been a couple of bugfix releases since then.  The latest patch version of the 9.2 series as of now is 9.2.8. See if you can get ahold of an updated version of GHC if you can control your environment, or if not tell whoever manages the lab to update it for you; See if it workes with the latest version.

Comment: Yes, this ghc has worked so far for all my code. I'll definitely try to update it to 9.2.8 and update here